# Populate ListFragments with a custom view?

Tags: android, listview, view, android-fragments, layout-inflater

previously, I had no problem with inflating a layout as a custom view hierarchy for a ListView. But I have no clue on how to do the same for a listFragment. Lets say I have an item_list layout with an ImageView and 2 textviews in it. I want to inflate this to be used in my ListFragment. But how??

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends ListFragment {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Vector<RowData> data;
RowData rd;

 static final String[] title = new String[] {
    "Classic Plank", "Side Plank", "Reversed Plank", "Swissball Plank", "One Arm One Leg", //5
    };

static final String[] description = new String[] {
    "Variation of Sushis from fresh vegetables and seafoods! Good for family occassions!",
    "Oyakodon is a Japanese Rice Bowl dish with Chicken, Eggs and various sorts of healthy and delicious Veggetables!",
    "Japanese assorted Pancake that is made from many different ingredients. The taste is so delicious!",
    "Japanese Dumplings made of Rice Flour. This is one of the healthiest sweets in Japan!",
    "Japanese assorted stews. Made from many different kind of veggetables. Popular in Winter!", //5
    };

private Integer[] imgid = {
 R.drawable.thumb_classic, R.drawable.thumb_side, R.drawable.thumb_reverse,      R.drawable.thumb_swissball, R.drawable.thumb_reachout, //5
};

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.easylist);
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
data = new Vector<RowData>();
for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){
    try {
        rd = new RowData(i,title[i],description[i]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    data.add(rd);
    }
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_main, android.R.id.list, data);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
   getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}


private void setContentView(int main) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


private LayoutInflater getSystemService(String layoutInflaterService) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}


public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("Layout", position);

Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ContentViewer.class);
newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
}
   private Context getApplicationContext() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}
private class RowData {
   protected int mId;
   protected String mTitle;
   protected String mDescription;
   RowData(int id, String title, String description){
   mId=id;
   mTitle = title;
   mDescription = description;
}
   @Override
   public String toString() {
           return mId+" "+mTitle+" "+mDescription;
   }
}
  private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {

  public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {               

 super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
}
@Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   

   ViewHolder holder = null;
   TextView title = null;
   TextView description = null;
   ImageView thumbnail = null;
   RowData rowData = getItem(position);
   if(null == convertView){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_main, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
 }
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         title = holder.gettitle();
         title.setText(rowData.mTitle);

         description = holder.getdescription();
         description.setText(rowData.mDescription);

         thumbnail = holder.getImage();
         thumbnail.setImageResource(imgid[rowData.mId]);
         return convertView;
}
        private class ViewHolder {
        private View mRow;
        private TextView title = null;
        private TextView description = null;
        private ImageView thumbnail = null; 

        public ViewHolder(View row) {
        mRow = row;
 }
    public TextView gettitle() {
         if(null == title){
             title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
            }
        return title;
     }     

     public TextView getdescription() {
         if(null == description){
              description = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.description);
                }
       return description;
     }

    public ImageView getImage() {
         if(null == thumbnail){
              thumbnail = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                                  }
            return thumbnail;
    }
 }            
}
}
```

Comment: It's exactly the same, use an adapter as with ListView and inflate your own layout.

Comment: @DavidCaunt I get an error on the adapter. I ported a listview form one of my app and changed "extends ListActivity" to "extends ListFragment". It says the adapter is undefined. Help???
Heres the code http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33331786/Errors/listfragment.txt

Comment: On this line:
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_main, android.R.id.list, data);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot remember for sure if this is what solved this problem when I had it, but I don't think you are correctly following the fragment lifecycle (seen [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)).

In the context of talking about an activity, you must first create your `ListView` before making calls like `setAdapter()`. You are implementing in `onCreate()` which is called before `onCreateView()`.

So it simply seems like you are in essence trying to set the adapter of your `ListView` before you have created it.

As a habit, it is always best to do all of your work with views within the `onCreateView()` part of the fragment lifecycle.